# Overrides method from class warning(s) - JWplayer iOS SDK

Tags: xcode, jwplayer

Prerequisites:

- Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)
- CocoaPods 0.39.0
- `pod 'JWPlayer-SDK', :inhibit_warnings => true`

> ld: warning: instance method 'clientNameForKey:' in category from
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig+PrivateContent.o)
>   overrides method from class in
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig.o)
>
> ld: warning: instance method 'setCaptions:' in category from
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig+PrivateContent.o)
>   overrides method from class in
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig.o)
>
> ld: warning: instance method 'captions' in category from
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig+PrivateContent.o)
>   overrides method from class in
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig.o)
>
> ld: warning: instance method 'setTracksList:' in category from
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig+PrivateContent.o)
>   overrides method from class in
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig.o)
>
> ld: warning: instance method 'tracksList' in category from
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig+PrivateContent.o)
>   overrides method from class in
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig.o)
>
> ld: warning: instance method 'setAdvertising:' in category from
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig+PrivateContent.o)
>   overrides method from class in
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig.o)
>
> ld: warning: instance method 'advertising' in category from
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig+PrivateContent.o)
>   overrides method from class in
>   /Users/wojtek/iOS/../Pods/JWPlayer-SDK/libJWPlayer-iOS-SDK.a(JWConfig.o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be resolved in 2.2.0: https://github.com/jwplayer/JWPlayer-iOS-SDK-cocoapod/issues/1